# Assembly could not be converted to type library - Error:Type library exporter cannot load type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to build one of the older components which uses **.NET Framework 2.0**

If I build same component with .Net Framework 4.0 it builds successfully but;

when .Net framework 2.0 is used, build fails with error "Assembly could not be converted to type library."

Following is complete error report for this error:

```
Error   14  The assembly "X:\MyAssembly.dll" could not be converted to a type library. Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'Namespace.ComponentName, ProjectName'. Error: Type library exporter cannot load type 'Namespace.ComponentName' (error: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, Assembly asm, SecurityAction action)
The action that failed was:
InheritanceDemand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
The first permission that failed was:
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="UnmanagedCode"/>

The demand was for:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="UnmanagedCode"/>
</PermissionSet>

The granted set of the failing assembly was:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Perm
```

I want to build this assembly on .Net framework 2.0

What should I do to get rid of this error. Please point me in the right direction...

Comment: Surely the X: drive is the problem, mapped network drives are in the IntraNet zone by default.  You'll have to tell that [you fully trust it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/12/30/using-caspol-to-fully-trust-a-share/)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by user Hans Passant, indeed X: drive was the problem.
I was not able to get it working using CASPOL command by giving it "full trust".
But, I was able to build when I mapped X: drive using SUBST command.

So, Mapping X: drive by using SUBST command fixed my issue.

`subst X: D:\XDriveFolderToBeMapped`